# What test is appropriate for my data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, chemometrics

I have three types of food (Fish, Beef, Pasta) and for each food I have the average of the pH level. For each food and pH level, I have three repeated measures showing the amount of aluminum. I want to check whether the amount of aluminum in food depends on the pH of food by adjusting for the effect of the type of food.

```
Type of food               Fish        Beef        Pasta
pH level                   6.1         7.8         4.8

Amount of Aluminum         12.2        13.1        9.8
                           11.4        12          10.3
                           12.6        12.5        10
```

Comment: Standard spelling is pH not PH.  You can't test averages alone; you need the original data for a test. This looks like analysis of variance or more generally a generalised linear model. I'd expect aluminum (aluminium) content to be skewed, so watch out.

Comment: Oh thank you. I corrected it. This is the data they have given me. I'm not even sure a parametric test would work out.

Comment: I don't see why not.  Sometimes data are in turn averages of other data, but you then have a very small sample size. Nevertheless (e.g.) the values for pasta are consistently lower than all others, so there is some pattern in the data. I know nothing about the food chemistry; subject-matter specialists may be able to advise further.

Comment: If these are the only data you have, then you cannot achieve your objective since the type of food and pH levels are *confounded*: although there is an apparent difference in mean amounts of aluminum, you have no basis to attribute those differences to the pH or the type of food; all you can conclude is that the differences are significant.

Comment: If the intent was to adjust the relationship for food type, I'm reminded of Fisher's quote (*to consult the statistician after an experiment is finished is often merely to ask him to conduct a post mortem examination. He can perhaps say what the experiment died of*) - in this case, confounding ... If the experiment is to be repeated, statistical advice will allow for more of information to be had from a similar level of effort (including basic advice such as having a design where the pH isn't identical within each food type and not averaging the data before analyzing it)

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comment:

> If these are the only data you have, then you cannot achieve your
> objective since the type of food and pH levels are confounded:
> although there is an apparent difference in mean amounts of aluminum,
> you have no basis to attribute those differences to the pH or the type
> of food; all you can conclude is that the differences are significant.

– whuber